# Рассылка приходит только одному пользователю

Tags: telebot, рассылка

Есть у меня функция, которая записывает id пользователей, а другая функция делает рассылку этим пользователям. Все было хорошо, но по непонятной причине уведомление стало приходить только одному пользователю, при этом вот что мне пишет python:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat_id is empty"
```

Фрагмент кода:

```
users_db = open("users.txt", "r")
JoinedUser = set()
for line in users_db:
    JoinedUser.add(line.strip())
users_db.close()
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in JoinedUser:
        users_db = open("users.txt", "a")
        users_db.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        users_db.close()
@bot.message_handler(commands=['new'])
def news(message):
    for user in JoinedUser:
        bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

Comment: Переведите текст ошибки и узнаете причину

Comment: @MyZik сам текст ошибки я перевел, но все равно не могу понять почему так

Answer (score 0):

Для начала тебе необходимо открыть файл, в котором записаны все id юзеров, дальше читать их
После уже проверка с использованием for
Код без ошибок с телефона не напишу, так что не буду позориться)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).